# How can I setup a web Application to use ADFS /SAML/WS-* in JAVA?

Tags: java, asp.net, wicket, saml, adfs

I have a pair of web applications written in **Java 1.6.X** using **Wicket-1.5.x** There is another organization where I work that maintains a public login portal for my web applications to integrate with that supplies user Identities via ADFS/SAML tokens.

They actually provide a sample application for me to look at but its written in ASP.net. The part of the application that does the checking of identities is using the *Windows Identity Foundation* classes and therefore is a non-starter.  Doing a web search on Converting ASP.net code to Java code I found [Grasshopper](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=130) but I have VS 2010 and it "requires" 2008 and wont install.

I've created a simple test page that displays all the cookies it can find and while I'm getting:  JSESSIONID, utma, utmz, utmb, utmc, none of my received cookies looks like a SAML token.

I've tried running the hosted version of the other organizations sample.  and the **Sample.domain.com** cookies don't even exist until **AFTER** there sample applications secure page loads.  So how do I get the identity information if the cookies are not CREATED until after my page is loaded?

is this where **WS-Federation** comes in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did eventually solve my problem.  I ended up Integrating [Apache CXF Fediz](http://cxf.apache.org/fediz) with my application.  It's still relatively new, but it works and with some tweaks was able to fulfill my needs.

Answer (score 0):

WIF uses WS-Federation and there's no Java equivalent that I'm aware of.

However, you can use SAML. Refer: [SAML : A SAML stack](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-stack.html).

Comment: I just recently found out about the [Fediz](http://cxf.apache.org/fediz.html) project.  It adds WS-Federation to [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org).